# Spark dataframe - transform rows with same ID to columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I want to transform below source dataframe (using pyspark):

| Key | ID | segment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | m1 |
| 2 | A | m1 |
| 3 | B | m1 |
| 4 | C | m2 |
| 1 | D | m1 |
| 2 | E | m1 |
| 3 | F | m1 |
| 4 | G | m2 |
| 1 | J | m1 |
| 2 | J | m1 |
| 3 | J | m1 |
| 4 | K | m2 |

Into below result dataframe:

| ID | key1 | key2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 3 | - |
| C | 4 | - |
| D | 1 | - |
| F | 3 | - |
| G | 4 | - |
| J | 1 | 2 |
| J | 1 | 3 |
| J | 2 | 3 |
| K | 4 | - |

In other words: I want to highlight the "pairs" in the dataframe - If I have more than one key for the same ID, I would like to point each relation in diferents lines.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions. I assume - means a one man group. If not you can use when/otherwise contion to blank the 1s out.

w =Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy(desc('Key'))

```
df= (df.withColumn('key2', lag('segment').over(w))# create new column with value of preceding segment for each row
     .withColumn('key2', col('key2').isNotNull())# query to create boolean selection
     .withColumn('key2',F.sum(F.col('key2').cast('integer')).over(w.rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, sys.maxsize))+1)#Create cumulative groups
     .orderBy('ID', 'key')#Reorder frame
    )

df.show()

+---+---+-------+----+
|Key| ID|segment|key2|
+---+---+-------+----+
|  1|  A|     m1|   2|
|  2|  A|     m1|   2|
|  3|  B|     m1|   1|
|  4|  C|     m2|   1|
|  1|  D|     m1|   1|
|  2|  E|     m1|   1|
|  3|  F|     m1|   1|
|  4|  G|     m2|   1|
|  1|  J|     m1|   2|
|  2|  J|     m1|   3|
|  3|  J|     m1|   3|
|  4|  K|     m2|   1|
+---+---+-------+----+
```

Comment: I presume, `rank` and then `count` might also work in place of `lag` here. Correct me if I have mistaken?

Comment: @Dipsy, feel free to add alternative code, there are many ways of killing an ogre